# How to find *.html file that includes template content when use asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am using knockoutJS with [external-template-engile](https://github.com/ifandelse/Knockout.js-External-Template-Engine) in asp.net mvc3.
I stored template contents in template.html file, but it creates 404 not found error that cannot find "template.html" file.
I guess this is because asp.net mvc prohibits direct access to specific view file under Views folder e.g. localhost/home/template.html"
How to solve this 404 error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct the web.config in the views folder in MVC prohibits all file requests. I wouldn't recommend changing this. The alternatives are, put the html file in a separate folder away from your views folder.

Or, create your template file as a .cshtml file, add a route say "/templates" and route to it instead. This would be my preferred choice. It's a nicer url and if you want to make the template page slightly dynamic in the future you can.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you elaborate with an example of a route for using cshtml files? I'm not getting it to work.

Comment: I wasn't referring to anything generic, just a standard ASP.NET MVC page. Controller Action + Views/ControllerName/Action.cshtml. It can use the default route or you can add route to the RouteTable in global.asax.